# Add a url link to a CSS class via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's possible to add a url link to my CSS class via JS?

Because I can't to edit my HTML file.

I have this CSS to change my logo when it scroll:

```
.she-header .logo img {
visibility: hidden;
    }

.she-header .logo {
    content:url(https://example.com/Logo2.png) !important;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 101px;
    width: 185px;
    }
```

But when it scroll I lose the url link to my home.

Someone can help me? Have a way to do it with JS?

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: You can always dynamically insert `<style>` tags to your header or body, with new rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css) method. Add this code to a scroll event handler:

```
$("target-element").css("content", "url(path)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla js :

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].style.content = "url(path)";
```